# recommendations for deploying web applications in an enterprise environment

Tags: deployment, web-deployment

I'm hoping some friendly folks out there can offer some advice on reliably and efficiently deploying a large, multi-tier, mission critical application to a farm of windows 2003 servers. Our current solution of custom powershell scripts is getting a bit creaky and is difficult to maintain. We need:

- the ability to define/enforce deploy "dependencies" such that application A is *always* deployed with application B
- permissions, possibly integrated w/ Active Directory
- fault tolerance. If something goes wrong in the deploy process, we need something to take automatic corrective action. We have too many servers to do this manually.
- flexibility. We have custom needs and need something easy to work with and extend.
- support for multiple environments.
- 'orchestration' tools, allowing us to remove a web server from the load balancer prior to deployment, then re-add when the deploy is successful.

How have other people solved this program? Are custom scripts the only way to go? Has anyone used UrbanDeploy?

Thank you for any advice on solving this problem!

Edit: I'd recommend anyone struggling with this issue to check out HP Operations Orchestration. This is the direction we're going to take.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend anyone struggling with this issue to check out HP Operations Orchestration. This is the direction we're going to take... has all the flexibility we need w/ a graphical interface, web component, security, permissions, pre-built integration tools... everything we were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Fair warning: I work for Urbancode which sells UrbanDeploy.

More people will have experience with our AnthillPro product than UrbanDeploy. UrbanDeploy is a newer product that separates the deployment abilities of AnthillPro into a separate product from build and CI. It also extends those capabilities to handle the multi-tier problem better.

But overall, yes, what you're talking about is exactly what we built the product to do. It groups applications or components into larger systems that are deployed together. It integrates with A/D and LDAP. Can automatically rollback or notify you so you choose to rollback or remove things from the load balancer. It's extensible through plugins. It treats the true deployment process as the combination of a consistent process and environment specifics (formally models environments), and does have integration with F5 (and soon more load balancers).